# When using a for loop in Javascript, how can I display output in multiple columns?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

The user should be able to enter in an integer and see the base, squared, and cubed result of that number. The base result should be listed under the "base" header, the squared result should be listed under the "squared" header and the cubed result should be listed under the "cubed" result. However, my output is listed all results under the "base" header. How can I make the results be listed under the related headers? This is what I have:

```
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var calculate = function () {

//Get the input from the user and assign it to the userInput variable
var integer = $("integer").value;

var header = "Base" + "  " + "Square" + "  " + "Cubed" + "\n";
var squared = "";
var cubed = "";
var base = "";
var displayOutput;

for (var i = 1; i <= integer; i++) {
    base += i + "\n";
    squared += i * i + "\n";
    cubed += i * i * i + "\n";
    displayOutput = base + squared + cubed;
    }

$("output").value = header + displayOutput;

}

var form_reset = function () {
    $("output").value = "";
    $("integer").value = "";
}

//Assign event handlers to their events
    window.onload = function () {
      $("powers").onclick = calculate;
      $("clear").onclick = form_reset;
    }
```

Comment: you might want to create a `html table` with your data.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the output. Trying to stay as close as possible to your code, seems you are inserting your resulting displayOutput string into a textarea control. If you want to keep it that way, try tabs (\t) to separate your columns, and only a new line at the end (\n). Also, I noticed you were concatenating every column (base, square, and cubed) on every iteration, so I removed that. Here's the result:

```
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

var calculate = function () {

//Get the input from the user and assign it to the userInput variable
var integer = $("integer").value;

var header = "Base" + "  " + "Square" + "  " + "Cubed" + "\n";
var squared = "";
var cubed = "";
var base = "";
var displayOutput = "";

for (var i = 1; i <= integer; i++) {
    base = i + "\t";
    squared = i * i + "\t";
    cubed = i * i * i + "\n";
    displayOutput += base + squared + cubed;
}

$("output").value = header + displayOutput;

};

var form_reset = function () {
    $("output").value = "";
    $("integer").value = "";
};

//Assign event handlers to their events
window.onload = function () {
  $("powers").onclick = calculate;
  $("clear").onclick = form_reset;
  $("theform").onsubmit = function() { return false; };
};
```